# Disable dynamic help in an eclipse plug-in?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm looking for a way to disable the "More results:" on the properties dialog of my Eclipse RCP plug-in (based on Eclipse 3.6.1).

Here is an example of what I'm trying to get rid of (not the exact properties).

I thought I had seen something about this a while ago, but can't find it anymore.

The `showSearchDescription` option looked promising, so I added 
`org.eclipse.help.base/showSearchDescription=false` to my plugin_customization.ini file, but that made no difference.

[image: Properties dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for this is in `org.eclipse.help.ui.internal.views.ContextHelpPart`. The statement that controls the inclusion of 'More results' is:

```java
if (!RelatedTopicsPart.isUseDynamicHelp() && searchTerms != null && searchTerms.length > 0)
```

`searchTerms` is the help data that was requested, so I think it will always be non-null and the length > 0.

`RelatedTopicsPart.isUseDynamicHelp()` tests an undocumented preference, but will cause other things to be shown on the dialog if it is changed (the preference is 'org.eclipse.help.base/show_dynamic_help').

So I don't think you will be able to turn of this section.